# Resolving ViewModel using Mef

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, mef

I am trying to test a wpf application that is developed in MVM pattern. So it includes the IregionManager, event aggregator etc. I have created a new project, and here I want to create an object of ViewModel and its constructor takes Iregionmanager. My question is How do i instantiate IRegionManager in my test class and create a ViewModel object so that I can access its methods?

Answer (score 0):

Why does your ViewModel require IRegionManager as a constructor parameter? Are you aware of the general concepts of Prism, such as the Bootstrapper, attaching behaviors to regions and, in more special cases, region adapters?

However, to answer your question, how to instantiate ViewModels: The general instantiation pattern in Prism with MEF:

A **Bootstrapper** is run at startup of the program, which among other tasks, creates **Behaviors** and attaches them to regions in your shell window. A behavior, which is called `AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior`, imports all Views with a specific  attribute, the *ViewExport* attribute. The **View** imports a **ViewModel** instance in its constructor and the **ViewModel** imports the **Model**.

I find the Prism architecture quite challenging to get started with. There's no way around really understanding the concepts if you want to work with it, though.

Comment: All I want is to create an object of a viewModel class. and I have to pass IRegionManager as its parameter after instantiating it. How do i do it?